# Using parameters in dictionary with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, dictionary, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

I'm using dictionary to hold all text used in the website like

```
var dict = {
  "text1": "this is my text"
};
```

Calling texts with javascript(jQuery),

```
$("#firstp").html(dict.text1);
```

And come up with a problem that some of my text is not static. I need to write some parameter into my text.

> You have 100 messages

```
$("#firstp").html(dict.sometext+ messagecount + dict.sometext);
```

and this is noobish

I want something like

```
var dict = {
  "text1": "you have %s messages"
};
```

How can I write "messagecount" in to where %s is.

Comment: Write your own printf in JS *and share it with the community* :-)

Comment: Why not simply use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) ?

Comment: I think replace is the best choice here. In any case your own printf in principle would make use of it, so I suggest you go ahead with that ;-).

Comment: So I conclude that your actual question has nothing to do with "dictionaries"?

Comment: duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+printf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any libraries, you may create your own easy string format function:

```
function format(str) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return str.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(m, i) {
        return args[i] !== undefined ? args[i] : m;
    });
}

format("you have {0} messages", 10);
// >> "you have 10 messages"
```

Or via `String` object:

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(m, i) {
        return args[i] !== undefined ? args[i] : m;
    });
};

"you have {0} messages in {1} posts".format(10, 5);
// >> "you have 10 messages in 5 posts"
```